# „A oder B? Beide geht“

Tags: difference, style, verb, grammatical-number

Ich habe oft „beide geht“ als eine Antwort auf eine Frage wie „soll man A oder B machen?“ gehört. „Beide“ ist aber Plural, also wurde ich „beide gehen“ sagen.

> Soll man HTML mit Regex oder mit einem richtigen Parser parsen?
>
> Beide geht/gehen.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Alternativen?

Comment: Erwähn bloß nicht auf SO, dass du HTML mit RegExp matchen willst; die töten dich sonst :D

Comment: @poke wobei ja eigentlich jeder parser nur eine große menge geschachtelter und wiederholter RegExps(?) ist

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Richtig muss es heißen

> Beides geht.

*Beides* ist ein Indefinitpronomen und bezeichnet die zusammengefasste Einheit von zwei Dingen. *Beides* ist außerdem im Singular, daher muss das Prädikat des Satzes *geht* heißen.
Alternativ kann man sagen

> Beide (Alternativen) gehen.

Hier ist *beide* nicht das Subjekt des Satzes, sondern beschreibt das ausgelassene Subjekt, das im Plural steht (hier im Beispiel *Alternativen*). In diesem Beispiel ist es ein Numerale, siehe [hier](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beide). Daher muss das Prädikat des Satzes *gehen* heißen.

Comment: Achso! Wahrscheinlich habe ich falsch gehört.

Comment: Höchstwahrscheinlich ein "beides", bei dem die letzte Silbe etwas verschluckt wurde. :)

Comment: *Beides* ist doch kein Substantiv. (* Das grüne Beide.) Das ist wie *alles* ein Indefinitpronomen.

Comment: @Debilski: Danke für den Hinweis, habe meine Antwort korrigiert.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ***"Beide" geht*** would work, too.
In this case it would be to clarify that the answer "Beide" is also possible (Answers: "A", "B", or "Beide").

A possible question would be:
"Welchen der Vorschläge möchten Sie umsetzen? A oder B? 'Beide' geht auch."

Comment: That's a bad example, because it's direct speech and has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @Sentry Well, for one it matches the headline if it's spoken. Since it is very unlikely, that TimN really got the answer _Beide geht_ to a question _A oder B?_, one possibility is, that he misheard the answer, as pointed out above. Another possiblity is, that he really heard _'Beide' geht_ one day in a case similar to my example, and mixed it up when he posted his question.

Comment: What I meant, was: `"XYZ" geht` works for whatever you put as `XYZ`. In your example, you're quoting arbitrary text. The most likely question in your example woulf be: "Welchen der Vorschläge möchten Sie umsetzen? A, B oder beide?

Comment: @Sentry Hm, I was building an example, of how TimN could have heard _'Beide' geht_ in the context of a choice question. Of course the quoted text is carefully chosen and not arbitrary. I could imagine somebody selling _A or B_, and then maybe half jokingly adding 'Both' would also be possible.